# EF Core is sharing tracked entities across instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1.26 with EntityFrameworkCore.Jet 3.1.1, using MS Access for the database. I would update EF Core, but then it wouldn't be compatible with EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.

My problem is that there seems to be some kind of static cache shared across instances. When after creating a instance I attach a entity, it throws an error because the entity is already being tracked, even though it is the first entity attached to that context (the queries are marked with AsNoTracking). I even checked with the debugger that there are no entities in the Entries property of the Change Tracker.

Even when I execute SaveChanges(), entities are updated that shouldn't exist in that context, since I made no query whatsoever. In the Entries property there is only the entity I attached with is navigation properties to null. And yet a bunch of entities of different tables are updated. Those entities I did query, but in another context and with AsNoTracking.

I have no idea where EF Core or EntityFrameworkCore.Jet are getting this entities from. It is like Attach and SaveChanges are accessing a static Change Tracker, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Edit: It was my mistake, I didn't check correctly.

Comment: Check the connection string.  The application should make a connection to the database to get initial values.  The connection is failing or you are not doing a query when application opens.  What may be happening is you query is in an event and the event is being called prematurely when your classes are being constructed.

Comment: It is not possible. Try do not attach entities but modify entities returned by DbContext - it is true EF way, otherwise you will have pain with ChangeTracker.